# Simplest C++ library that supports distributed messaging - Observer Pattern

Tags: c++11, asynchronous, boost, signals, distributed

I need to do something relatively simple, and I don't really want to install a MOM like RabittMQ etc.

1. There are several programs that "register" with a central
       "service" server through TCP. The only function of the server is to
       call back all the registered clients when they all in turn say
       "DONE". So it is a kind of "join" (edit: Barrier) for distributed client processes.
2. When all clients say "DONE" (they can be done at totally different times), the central server messages
       them all saying "ALL-COMPLETE". The clients "block" until asynchronously called back.

So this is a kind of distributed asynchronous Observer Pattern. The server has to keep track of where the clients are somehow. It is ok for the client to pass its IP address to the server etc. It is constructable with things like Boost::Signal, BOOST::Asio, BOOST::Dataflow etc, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if something simple already exists. I got very close with ZeroMQ, but non of their patterns support this use-case very well, AFAIK.

Is there a very simple system that does this? Notice that the server can be written in any language. I just need C++ bindings for the clients.

Comment: I can write other programs at reasonable rates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching, I used this library

https://github.com/actor-framework

It turns out that doing this with this framework is relatively straightforward. The only real "impediment" to using it is that the library seems to have gotten an API transition recently and the documentation .pdf file has not completely caught up with the source. No biggie since the example programs and the source (.hpp) files get you over this hump. However, they need to bring the docs in sync with the source. In addition, IMO they need to provide more interesting examples on how to use c++ Actors for extreme performance. For my case it is not needed, but the idea of actors (shared nothing) in this use-case is one of the reasons people use it instead shared memory communication when using threads.

Also, getting used to the syntax that the library enforces (get used to lambdas!) if one is not used to state of the art c++11 programs it can be a bit of a mind-twister at first. Then, the triviality of remembering all the clients that registered with the server was the only other caveat.

STRONGLY RECOMMENDED.